# I get this error with betfair API : "{'code': -32602, 'message': 'DSC-0018'}" using Python

Tags: python, json-rpc, betfair

I tried this code, which is taken from the Betfair site, but it doesn't work with `listMarketCatalogue`, while for example with `listEventTypes` it works:

```
endpoint = "https://api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/json-rpc/v1/"
user_req='{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/listMarketCatalogue", "params": {"filter":{}} , "id": 1}'
header1 = { 'X-Application' : mykey, 'X-Authentication' : SSOID, 'content-type': 'application/json'}

req=requests.post(endpoint,data=user_req.encode('utf-8'),headers=header1)

print(req.json())
```

and it gives me this error:

> {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'error': {'code': -32602, 'message': 'DSC-0018'}, 'id': 1}

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search shows that `DSC-0018` corresponds with an error relating to a missing parameter. ([Source](https://forum.developer.betfair.com/forum/developer-program/feedback-and-recommendations/32357-error-dsc-0018-32602))

A cursory review of [the relevant documentation](https://docs.developer.betfair.com/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/listMarketCatalogue) shows you're not passing the required parameter `maxResults`. Add it to your JSON-RPC call's `params` structure with a valid value (`0 < maxResults <= 10000`, according to the docs at the time of this writing).